# python : an integer is required (got type str)

Tags: python

I just need to print a list of int to ASCII.

```
a=list(str(12345))
for q in a:
    print(chr(q))
```

> an integer is required (got type str)

why I'm getting that error?

Comment: because `chr` expects an integer and you're giving it a string, i think maybe you're looking for `ord(q)`

Comment: [`chr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) takes an integer, i guess you are looking for [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord)

Comment: `a` is not a `list` of `int` but a `list` of `str`; `['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']` specifically.

Comment: `q` is a string because you are iterating over the list of characters `a`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to print?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing a string value into the chr() function. This should work:

```
a=list(str(12345))
for q in a:
    print(chr(int(q)))

#The above code will work but this will print out characters, as 1-5
# in the ASCII table are not visible characters.

a = [65,66,67,68,69]
for q in a:
    print(chr(q))
```

Comment: That's because 1,2,3,4, and 5 are not really characters. Check out this link: asciitable.com If you want to see characters view the second snippet of code above.